# How to add field to global object during test run?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to add a field to the global object during the test run

global-setup.ts

```js
module.exports = async (config, projectConfig) => {
...
global.someone = 1;
...
};
```

testfile.test.ts

```js
describe('sometitle', ()=>{
   test('testTitle', () => {
       try{
           console.log(global.someone) // 1;
           expect(false).toBe(true);
       } catch (e) {
           global.sometwo = 2;
           throw(e);
       }
   })
})
```

global-teardown.ts

```js
module.exports = async function (globalConfig, projectConfig) {
...
console.log(global.someone); // 1
console.log(global.sometwo); // undefined
...
}
```

The 'sometwo' field that initiates during the test run is undefined while running the global teardown.

The global setup/teardown should run once for all test suites.

Any ideas?

Comment: I found that Jest uses Object.freeze() for global objects. my solution for now is to init nested objects within the global setup for all my properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a configuration file, e.g.:

```
// testConfig.js
module.exports = {
  someone: 1,
};
```

Update your global setup to load this configuration:

```
// global-setup.ts
const testConfig = require('./testConfig');

module.exports = async (config, projectConfig) => {
  global.testConfig = testConfig;
};
```

Modify your test to access the configuration

```
// testfile.test.ts
describe('sometitle', () => {
  test('testTitle', () => {
    try {
      console.log(global.testConfig.someone); // 1;
      expect(false).toBe(true);
    } catch (e) {
      global.testConfig.sometwo = 2;
      throw e;
    }
  });
});
```